# Show ContextMenu only when Right clicked mouse is over on a specific datagridrow WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, contextmenu, datagridrow

I have a Page with a datagrid --> xaml code below:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" 
    IsReadOnly="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
    BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    ColumnWidth="Auto" Focusable="False" 
    MouseDoubleClick="DataGridArticoli_MouseDoubleClick" 
    GridLinesVisibility="None" 
    HeadersVisibility="Column" 
    UseLayoutRounding="False" 
    SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged">

    <!--Columns-->
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn col_1/>
        <DataGridTextColumn col_2/>
        <DataGridTextColumn col_3/>
        <DataGridTextColumn col_4/>
        <DataGridTextColumn col_5/>
        <DataGridTextColumn col_6/>
        <DataGridTextColumn col_7/>
        <DataGridTextColumn col_8/>
        <DataGridTextColumn col_9/>
        <DataGridTextColumn col_10/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="Remove_ContextMenuClick">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="/resources/delete.png"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem x:Name="btnOpen" Header="Open" Click="Open_ContextMenuClick" IsEnabled="False">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="/resources/open.png"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    
</DataGrid>
```

In this case context menu appear in each position of the mouse (when right clicked). I want show the context menu only in the selected row and only when mouse pointer is over the row selected. I tried different solutions, but I didn't find the right one. Someone can help me with some example code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `RowStyle` with a `Trigger`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid"  ...>

    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="Remove_ContextMenuClick">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="/resources/delete.png"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem x:Name="btnOpen" Header="Open" Click="Open_ContextMenuClick" IsEnabled="False">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="/resources/open.png"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>

</DataGrid>
```

Comment: If you can read the other post with other informations. Thank you

Comment: @Raffaele: What?